# Creating Google persistent disks from snapshots in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, gce-persistent-disk

I need to run pods on multiple nodes with very large (700GB) readonly dataset in Kubernetes. I tried using readonlymany, but it fails in multi-node setup, and in general was very unstable.

Is there a way for pods to create a new persistent disk from a snapshot, attach it to the pod, and destroy it when pod is destroyed?  This would allow me to update snapshots once in a while with the new data.

Comment: Automating this, is not possible because the pods would have to create the disk; but the pod can't be created until the disk exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually provision a persistent disk using an existing image on GCP:

```
gcloud beta compute disks create --size=500GB --image=<snapshot-name>  my-data-disk
```

Then use it on your pod:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-pd
spec:
  containers:
  - image: k8s.gcr.io/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-pd
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    # This GCE PD must already exist.
    gcePersistentDisk:
      pdName: my-data-disk
      fsType: ext4
```

The GCE storage class doesn't support snapshots so unfortunately, you can't do it with PVCs. More info [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#gce)

Hope it helps.

Comment: right, but that means i have to manage the pods by hand. Also, this approach is not scalable - i have to manually create each pod and each disk.  plus it doesn't clean up on destroy.

Comment: Yes, you have to build your own automation at this moment. You can always push for a KEP (Kubernetes Enhancement Proposal) in the Kubernetes community.